# Customizing ActionBar Sherlock

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I customize my action bar to be equal to Google Maps. I would like to add an icon on my list navigation.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The contents of list navigation is controlled by the `SpinnerAdapter` that you supply to `setListNavigationCallbacks()`. You should be able to create a `SpinnerAdapter` that uses icons and labels for the drop-down view, by [overriding `getDropDownView()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SpinnerAdapter.html#getDropDownView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29) and inflating/formatting the rows as you see fit.